# manifest delete SET_WALLPAPER permission when export

Tags: android, export, manifest, signing

sorry my english

I am exporting signed apk, and when eclipse finish exporting, the manifest.xml automaticaly delete this code file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

somebody knows why manifest reload without this permision? Obviusly the app doesn't run ok without this.

Thanks for all, and sorry my english

Comment: I think it is solved: Project -> Android tools -> Fix Project properties
Thanks for the reply

Comment: sorry, where is the check mark that you comment me?

Remember it's my first time, and do not understand English well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is solved: Project -> Android tools -> Fix Project properties Thanks for the reply