# how to prevent eclipse from regenerating manifest file when creating APK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-manifest, apk

I'm trying to export my application to a signed APK in order to upload to Google Play.
The problem I have is that eclipse is regenerating the AndroidManifest.xml File during the process and all the permissions that I defined are deleted.
I really appreciate any advice on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use Android Developer Tools IDE.

Comment: see this post. Similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493486/manifest-delete-set-wallpaper-permission-when-export

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, but, non is working. I did see the old posts and did try them before posting my question. Can you think of something else that may prevent AndroidManifest.xml from being set to default every time I create an APK?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
I found an aggressive way to solve it.
Right click on the AndroidManifest.xml --> properties --> change to "Read-only".
Make sure you change the AndroidManifest.xml in the root directory and not in the "bin" directory.

Thanks for all your support.